# Блокировать по ip-адресу. Простой способ

Tags: apache, nginx, freebsd

Здравствуйте.Есть веб-сервер nginx+apche на FreeBSD.Неоднократно сталкиваюсь с ситуацией когда с одного ip-адреса поступает очень много запросов.По десять запросов в секунду и так на протяжении пяти минут. После чего сервер ложиться.

Как сделать так, чтобы Nginx или Apache или ФаерВолл FreeBSD блокировал этот ip-адрес?И больше не обрабатывал запросы от этого айпишника.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fail2Ban to limit DDOS attacks on http webserver](http://www.dedmeet.com/software-projects-mainmenu-12/fail2ban-to-limit-ddos-attacks-on-webserver.html)

Answer (score 1):

И в чём проблема? 1. `block quick from ip_address to any` - в конфиг pf, затем pfctl -f path_to_config_pf_file (это жёстко) 2.     `Order allow,deny`        `allow from all`        `Deny from ip_address` - в .htaccess (это более лояльно)

Answer (score 0):

А у меня вообще хардовый рутер с отсечкой! Подозреваю, что примерно таким вот способом.